# Constructors and Copy Constructors accross Identical derived classes

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, derived-class, base-class

Is it possible to use a copy constructor to initialize an identical derived class from that derived classes "twin"?

I mean I want to initialise an object of type `Computer` that is identical to an object I already initialised of type `User`.
`Computer cCarrier = User uCarrier;` Kind of thing.

E.g

```
class Game
{
public:
    //No constructor Intentional
protected:
    int m_iSize;
    string m_strName;

};

class User: public Game
{
public: 
    User(int _iSize, string str_Name);
    ~User();

};

class Computer: public Game
public: 
    Computer(int _iSize, string str_Name);
    ~Computer();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "game.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     User carrier(5, "Airship Carrier");
     //Computer carrier = User::carrier;
};
```

They are identical derived classes, I have only made them this way as a virtual and visual way to represent the `User` and AI battleships in the programming code, for the programmer, and for testing a sides ships for collisions against each other and firing shots.

Comment: when you say in your code 'No constructor Intentional', you do realize there are implicitely declared constructors?

Comment: You can write constructors taking any kind of object. `Computer::Computer( User const & other ) { /* ... */ }` -- what you make that copy constructor *do* so this makes sense is up to you. And in order to access any of `User`'s private members you'd need to use the dreaded `friend`...

Comment: I think you need to define a constructor in Computer that takes a user as parameter.

Comment: If they are "identical", why two separate classes?

Comment: Some of the implementations of `Game` here lack [virtual destructors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/07/127826.aspx) and will lead to undefined behaviour. I know it's not central to the question, but still worth pointing out. Be safe and use this with all your non-`final` (which is a really helpful new C++11 keyword) classes.

Answer (score 0):

`User` and `Computer` are different type at all. You can add a template copy constructor for it.

Add getter in the base class:

```
class Game
{
public:
    //No constructor Intentional
    int get_iSize() { return m_iSize; }
    string get_strName() { return m_strName; }
protected:
    int m_iSize;
    string m_strName;

};
```

then

```
class Computer: public Game
{
public: 
    template <typename T>
    Computer(const T& t) {
        m_iSize = t.get_iSize();
        m_strName = t.get_strName();
    }
    // ...
};
```

And consider to make the constructor explicit to avoid unexpected implicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

Well either you want 2 different types and then you cannot do that ( cannot create a Cat from a Dog), or you want them to share the same type but to be manipulated thru different typenames then you should just use a typedef:

```
class Game
{
public:
   Game(int _iSize, string str_Name);
private:
    int m_iSize;
    string m_strName;
};

using User = Game;
using Computer = Game;
```

Nevertheless, from a design standpoint, this way of doing it seem incorrect as a Computer is not a User (IMHO).

On another hand, you could create a constructor in user and in Computer that builds from a Game; something like:

```
class Computer {
  Computer(const Game &game) : Game(game) { /*...*/ }
  /*...*/
};
```

but remains the fact that building a User from a Computer seems "strange".

Comment: He's implementing a game of Battleships. He's got one class for `User` ships, and one for `Computer` ships. Generally bad design, I agree, but that's why he's looking at creating / assigning a `Computer` ship from a `User` one.

Answer (score 0):

The only relationship between your `User` and `Computer` types is that they both derive from `Game`.

As such, there is no way to implement a constructor of either by delegating to the other in the way you want  (short of containment, which is creating distinct objects, not using the constructor of one type to initialise an instance of an unrelated type).